# Filter similar DNA sequences using R

Tags: r, sequence, similarity

I have two tables containing DNA sequences from an early stage (TIMEPOINT_1) and a later stage (TIMEPOINT_2). I would like to filter the TIMEPOINT_2 table for sequences from the TIMEPOINT_1 table that have a similarity threshold of 95%. I have tried using the 'stringdistmatrix' function and also creating similarity matrices, but I haven't achieved the desired results. Is there a way to do this in R?

Here's an example with the table structure:

```
# Creating df TIMEPOINT_1
sequences <- c(
  "ACCTTCAGGCAACCTTCAGGCA",
  "ACCTTCGAGCAGCCATCAGGCA",
  "ACCCGTCCTAGGATCGATCAGGCA",
  "TCGAAGTGCATGCATGCTTACGTA",
  "CGTGCAAAGCGTGACGTTAGCGT")
sequence_names <- c("time1_seq1", "time1_seq2", "time1_seq3", "time1_seq4", "time1_seq5")
TIMEPOINT_1 <- data.frame(name = sequence_names, sequence = sequences)

# Creating df TIMEPOINT_2
sequences <- c(
  "ACCTTCGGGCAACCTTCAGGCA",
  "ACCTTCGTGCGGGCCATCAGGCA",
  "ACCCGTCCTAGGATCGATCAGGCA",
  "TCGAAGTGCATGCATGCTTAAGTA",
  "CGTGCAAAGCGTGACTGCACGTGGT")
sequence_names <- c("time2_seq1", "time2_seq2", "time2_seq3", "time2_seq4", "time2_seq5")
TIMEPOINT_2 <- data.frame(name = sequence_names, sequence = sequences)
```

The expected result: a TIMEPOINT_2 table containing matching sequences from the TIMEPOINT_1 table.

Comment: this comes up frequently enough on SO, look for `stringdist` and `fuzzyjoin::stringdist_*`

Comment: which(stringdist::stringsim(sequences1, sequences2) >= 0.950)
[1] 1 3 4. without which(, returns vector of similarities, [1] 0.9545455 0.8695652 1.0000000 0.9583333 0.8000000. Just renamed to 1 and 2 to distinguish but their order in stringsim(a, b or (b, a doesn't change the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your goals I would perform a simple inner merge:

```r
df <- merge(TIMEPOINT_1, TIMEPOINT_2, by = "sequence", all = F) ## Inner merge is set with all = F
df
```